# Symfony Algolia Search Engine Association Indexing

Tags: symfony, indexing, foreign-keys, associations, algolia

I have a product entity, and each product is assigned to a category which is a separate category entity which is joined with a categoryId property in my product Entity. I have indexed all of the properties that I need such as name price etc, but I can't get my categoryId to index correctly:

[image]
[image]

When this it is indexed I get an array but not with the actual category Id or other information associated in that category:

[image]

So my question is, what is the correct way of going about this so that the category my product is assigned to is indexed correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two problems:

**First**:
You put on property and method, you must chose one.

**Second**:
With symfony when you make a ManyToOne like this

```
$this->categoryId
```

return an object, you can't map entire object with algolia attribute.

I suggest you to just make one method like this:

```
/*
 * @Algolia\Attribute
 */    
function getCategoryName() {
    return $this->categoryId->getName();
}
```

Comment: Actually now I looked at it again it didn't totally work as intended, the method worked within symfony and when i run the command to index the entity to algolia it says 'successful' but there is no category name in algolia's index. This is the method I used:

/*
     * @Algolia\Attribute(algoliaName="categoryName")
     */    
    public function getCategoryName() {
        return $this->categoryId->getName();
    }

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact I have no categoryName property? But I tried making one and it still didn't work so not entirely sure here.

Comment: Are you sure your category have a name? :)
Did you try to reindex wih --unsafe:
php app/console algolia:reindex SomeBundle:EntityName --unsafe

Comment: Yeh my category deffo has a name and getName method. This is my product entity: https://pastebin.com/9FBfF0qs and my category: https://pastebin.com/hx3HW3ND the command you said to try just did the same as without the --unsafe command, said entities are indexed, but the categoryName is still not there in algolia. The getCategoryName() is right at the bottom of my Product entity.

Comment: remove attributesToIndex=... l.13 in product entity

Comment: Ok done that, still no luck though it's still not in the algolia index :(. Also tried clearing my cache and deleted the index and created it again but still the same :S

Comment: Must be a bug with any custom methods I create because I even tried their example with getting a name and price here https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/symfony/mapping-entities-to-algolia-indexes/#indexing-entity-properties-or-methods and that is not working either :S

Comment: No problem i used it a lot of time... Give me your product file again

Comment: https://pastebin.com/R3HqGrdt Theres a few more methods and properties in there this time, I removed them last time so there wasen't as much scrolling but I left it all in this time in case there is something.

Comment: The weird thing is if I move the contents of that method (return $this->categoryId->getName();) to another method such as getName() which is a mapped property, then the category is indexed perfectly. So I guess it's custom unmapped methods that it won't allow me to index rather than anything wrong with sytax.

Comment: Just randomly managed to fix this by removing the algolia attribute from the getCategoryName method and created a field called $categoryName with the same algolia attribute attached to it. Weird that it wouldn't just work on the method. But either way thanks for your time helping with this!

Comment: Actually scrap that, I just discovered that the real issue was a syntax issue lol, on the anotation: '/
     * @Algolia\Attribute(algoliaName="categoryName")
     */' I was missing a second star it should be like this '/**
     * @Algolia\Attribute(algoliaName="categoryName")
     */' Lol so frustrating...

Comment: Lol! Use a real ide like phpstorm next time!